# how to get drag event in d3.js in javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following is the code for drawing a force directed graph in javascript using d3.js

```js
const graph = {
  nodes: [{
      name: 'john',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'simon',
      age: 37
    },
    {
      name: 'manjoor',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'lorg',
      age: 34
    },
    {
      name: 'kilvin',
      age: 32
    },
  ],
  links: [{
      source: 'john',
      target: 'simon'
    },
    {
      source: 'john',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
    {
      source: 'simon',
      target: 'lorg'
    },
    {
      source: 'simon',
      target: 'kilvin'
    },
    {
      source: 'manjoor',
      target: 'kilvin'
    },
    {
      source: 'lorg',
      target: 'john'
    },
    {
      source: 'lorg',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
    {
      source: 'kilvin',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
  ]
}


const canvas = d3.select('#network')

const width = canvas.attr('width')
const height = canvas.attr('height')
const r = 30
const ctx = canvas.node().getContext('2d')

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeAccent);

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(r + 20))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(node => node.name))
  .on('tick', update)


simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
simulation.force('link').links(graph.links)

canvas.call(d3.drag()
  .container(canvas.node())
  .subject(dragsubject).on('start', dragstarted)
  .on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended)
)



function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
  graph.links.forEach(drawLink)
  ctx.stroke()


  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1
  graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode)
  ctx.fill()
}



function dragsubject(event) {
  return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y)
}

function drawNode(d) {

  ctx.fillStyle = color(d.party)
  ctx.moveTo(d.x, d.y)
  ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
}

function drawLink(l) {
  ctx.moveTo(l.source.x, l.source.y)
  ctx.lineTo(l.target.x, l.target.y)
}

function dragstarted(event) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
  event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
}

function dragged(event) {
  event.subject.fx = event.x;
  event.subject.fy = event.y;
}

function dragended(event) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  event.subject.fx = null;
  event.subject.fy = null;
}

update()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
<canvas id="network" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

I'm getting the graph on the canvas.

However I'm getting the following error:

[image]

& when I debug I can see that here is where error occurs  `return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y)` ... seems like event is missing... is there a way to solve this. this happens on drag... & so dragging each node is not working.

or can someone suggest a way to drag nodes...

Comment: What version of d3 are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version... Just installed.

Comment: Is there a way to make the nodes dragging ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using d3 version 6. `d3.event` has been removed. Please read [the change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) carefully, downgrade your d3 version, or look for more up to date examples.

```js
const graph = {
  nodes: [{
      name: 'john',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'simon',
      age: 37
    },
    {
      name: 'manjoor',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'lorg',
      age: 34
    },
    {
      name: 'kilvin',
      age: 32
    },
  ],
  links: [{
      source: 'john',
      target: 'simon'
    },
    {
      source: 'john',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
    {
      source: 'simon',
      target: 'lorg'
    },
    {
      source: 'simon',
      target: 'kilvin'
    },
    {
      source: 'manjoor',
      target: 'kilvin'
    },
    {
      source: 'lorg',
      target: 'john'
    },
    {
      source: 'lorg',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
    {
      source: 'kilvin',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
  ]
}


const canvas = d3.select('#network')

const width = canvas.attr('width')
const height = canvas.attr('height')
const r = 30
const ctx = canvas.node().getContext('2d')

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeAccent);

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(r + 20))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(node => node.name))
  .on('tick', update)


simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
simulation.force('link').links(graph.links)

canvas.call(d3.drag()
  .container(canvas.node())
  .subject(dragsubject).on('start', dragstarted)
  .on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended)
)



function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
  graph.links.forEach(drawLink)
  ctx.stroke()


  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1
  graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode)
  ctx.fill()
}



function dragsubject(event) {
  return simulation.find(event.x, event.y);
}

function drawNode(d) {

  ctx.fillStyle = color(d.party)
  ctx.moveTo(d.x, d.y)
  ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
}

function drawLink(l) {
  ctx.moveTo(l.source.x, l.source.y)
  ctx.lineTo(l.target.x, l.target.y)
}

function dragstarted(event) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
  event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
}

function dragged(event) {
  event.subject.fx = event.x;
  event.subject.fy = event.y;
}

function dragended(event) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  event.subject.fx = null;
  event.subject.fy = null;
}

update()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
<canvas id="network" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok. Great. Thanks. I will look in to this.

Comment: One more help. is there a way to use d3.js with konva.js?

Comment: Never heard of it, sorry

Comment: Hi Ruben Helsoot how to apply drag only while dragging. a node? currently wherever you click on the stage a node is getting dragged

Comment: I'm confused, didn't I [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302292/5015356) already?